# How to create a ion-select which is graphically like a ion-input?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3, css-position

What I want to obtain is a [`<ion-select>`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select) that is equal to a [`<ion-input>`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#stacked-labels) with a stacked label.

**What I have now:**

[image: Ion select]

**What I want:**

[image: Ion input]

Of course, this one should have the little triangle on the right to make the selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as such:

.html

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item style="padding-bottom: 10px; min-height: 6.4rem;">
        <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Music</ion-label>
        <ion-select style="height: 100%; padding-bottom: 0px; font-weight: 500;">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let temp of musicArr">{{ temp.name }}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

[image]

Comment: Ok that works, but there is only one problem. The label in this case "Music", disappears after the option of the list is selected. How can I fix that?

Comment: Nevermind it works now. I've just rewritten it in the most simple way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in functionality for that. You could build your own, but it's quite an involved undertaking. Fortunately, there is a custom component called [ionic-select-searchable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-select-searchable?activeTab=readme) that does this:

[image: ionic-select-searchable in action]

Just install it according to the instructions on that page and add it to your page.